# og:image functions.php

Tags: wpdb

I have custom template and i need get og:image url in header.
Class image location in DB  wp_postmeta - meta_value
i try with functions.php

```
function getOgImage()
{
    global $wpdb;
    $ogimage = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT DISTINCT post_id FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_value", OBJECT);

    echo '<meta property="og:image" content="'.$ogimage.'"/>';
}
add_action('wp_head', 'getOgImage');
```

Im geting out:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="Array" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `var_dump($ogimage);` to understand the contents of `$ogimage` presumably it's returning an array of records from the database.

Generally you would retrieve post meta values with get_post_meta

[WordPress Docs for get_post_meta()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/)

Also there are plugins that sort out the og tags for you such as Yoast SEO

[Yoast SEO plugin page on WordPress site](https://en-gb.wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-seo/)

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved!

Code:

```
function getOgImage()
{
    global $wpdb;
    $ogimage = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), '_wcs_image', true);

    if($ogimage)
        echo '<meta property="og:image" content="'.$ogimage.'"/>';
}

add_action('wp_head', 'getOgImage');
```

Thanks to Bob!